# Apache wicket, insert panel without html tags

Tags: java, wicket

I have a panel for example myPanel, when I want to insert it in HTML markup I have to write

```
     <div wicket:panel="mypanel"/> or <span wicket:panel="mypanel"/>
```

at the Html output, my panel turns around div or span tags. Is it possible to somehow embed the panel in the HTML markup without the html tag, like

```
     <wicket:child/>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can always use [`wicket:container`](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WICKET/Wicket%27s+XHTML+tags#Wicket'sXHTMLtags-Elementwicket:container). It's elements are completely removed from the produced markup when Wicket is run in production mode.

Another option you can try is calling the [`setRenderBodyOnly(true)`](https://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.x/org/apache/wicket/Component.html#setRenderBodyOnly(boolean)) method of your Wicket panel.

Comment: Good answer! Note that you won't be able to do ajax-updates on this exact panel anymore because it won't have a markup-tag to put the id on.

Comment: Indeed. In a case where you use this solution to avoid invalid html but need ajax updates, you can always wrap the set of components in a WebMarkupContainer and update this container.